# Negative Hurst exponent

Tags: mean-reversion, hurst-exponent

I am trying to test Hurst exponent in different time lag range. However, i got negative values in some time lag range which is weird, because the Hurst exponent should have values within the range from 0 to 1.

This is the Python code to calculate the Hurst exponent:

```
*calculate Hurst*
lag1 = 2
lags = range(lag1, 20)

tau = [sqrt(std(subtract(ts[lag:], ts[:-lag]))) for lag in lags]

plot(log(lags), log(tau)); show()
m = polyfit(log(lags), log(tau), 1)

hurst = m[0]*2

print 'hurst = ',hurst
```

When `lags = range(200,300)`, the Hurst exponent is -0.035. My data length is 1643. The log-log plot looks like this, which is not linear:
[image]

---

**Is there something wrong with the code or anyone know any good package to test hurst exponent in R or python?**

Comment: I got similar results on some indices when I looked at this too. What underlying are you taking returns of?

Comment: I am using Shanghai composite Index

Answer (score 0):

Hurst exponent could be negative due to some data approximations. By design, it should stop at 0. In python, you coul look at `hurst` repository.

[Reference] https://towardsdatascience.com/introduction-to-the-hurst-exponent-with-code-in-python-4da0414ca52e